# Come si dice "live streaming" in italiano?

Tags: translation, nouns

Ciao a tutti!

Stavo guardando un video, che potete trovare a [questo link](http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/2016/11/26/referendum-la-costituzione-e-nostra-svelati-nuovi-ospiti-ovadia-guzzanti-della-rovere-e-bergonzoni/3219449/), in cui viene utilizzata l'espressione "in diretta streaming". Mi sarei aspettato, però, che ci fosse una parola italiana per "streaming". Ne esiste una?

Comment: Se c'è, io non la conosco.

Comment: Just so that people do not have to follow the link, the sentence pronounced in the video is *ci sarà un collegamento in diretta streaming [sul sito del Fatto Quotidiano]*, which loosely translates as *there will be a live stream [on the Fatto Quotidiano website]*.

Comment: I think no one is criticizing your Italian. As you can see [here](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/a/1261)
I've always encouraged people learning Italian trying to write their questions in Italian. What @DaG is saying is that some of your sentences are sometimes difficult to understand and then it may be useful you give some explanation in English (in a comment, if you want).

Comment: With your sentence "ha indicato una parola in diretta streaming" you are trying to say that, in the video, you have heard some word that you haven't understood very well followed by the expression "in diretta streaming"?

Comment: La parola "streaming" viene indicata come neologismo dall'[Osservatorio della lingua italiana Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/neologismi/searchNeologismi.jsp?lettera=S&pathFile=/sites/default/BancaDati/Osservatorio_della_Lingua_Italiana/OSSERVATORIO_DELLA_LINGUA_ITALIANA_ND_016793.xml&lettera=S).

Comment: @Charo thank you, I also suggested the same,  also the link about the language of the site was a very good discussion

Comment: @Farzad64 It is still not clear what you prefer we do to help you improve your question: you do not want us to edit it directly, but you also feel offended when pointed out mistakes. Could you clarify what you think we should do?

Comment: I have removed some comments that are not relevant to the question. Which doesn't mean I consider the discussion irrelevant: we all should be polite and helpful towards people whose first language is not Italian.

Comment: A dire il vero una traduzione esiste, ovvero "flusso". Ma sarebbe *cacofonico* dire "Guardo un video in flusso", per questo motivo viene utilizzata la versione inglese.

Comment: @Tyler: Non ho mai sentito la parola *flusso* adoperata in questo significato (per quanto sia la traduzione di *stream* nel senso letterale). Hai qualche riferimento per caso?

Comment: @Tyler: Perché sarebbe *cacofonico*?

Answer (score 4):

Nell'ambito delle nuove tecnologie sono molto frequenti in italiano i [neologismi di origine inglese](http://www.tesionline.it/default/tesi.asp?idt=38699). Come indicato dall'[Osservatorio della lingua italiana Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/neologismi/searchNeologismi.jsp?lettera=S&pathFile=/sites/default/BancaDati/Osservatorio_della_Lingua_Italiana/OSSERVATORIO_DELLA_LINGUA_ITALIANA_ND_016793.xml&lettera=S), il termine "streaming" è appunto uno di questi neologismi. L'espressione "live streaming" si può tradurre in italiano come hai sentito nel video, "in diretta streaming" (che è però una locuzione avverbiale), oppure come "[streaming in diretta](http://streamingindiretta.com/streaming/)" (questa sì usata come un nome).